# Ubuntu MATE xrandr - can't open display

Tags: xrandr, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

Got an Raspberry PI running Ubuntu mate. There is a screen connected to it through HDMI, it displays everything in the right resolution. But if i want to rotate the screen with xrandr i get "can't open display".

Does anybody know an alternative for rotating the screen? Or an easy solution for this problem? I'm a linux newbie.

Comment: Please add the full command you used and the output of `xrandr` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/914083/edit) to your question.

Comment: It just says "Can't open display". But i found a way around, just delete the comment in /etc/boot.txt "enable_rotation".